# Espresso check if TextView text and ImageView Drawable are together

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-espresso

I have a ConstraintLayout that is a list item inside of a GridView, so there will be multiple of them on the screen. There are various statuses for each item, which are represented by drawables, and each list item has a unique name in a TextView displayed above the drawable.

Basically I have these two inside a Constraint Layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/client_state_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/client_state_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_client"
        style="@style/ClientName"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Where `client_state_background` can be one of multiple drawables, determined programmatically.

I'm trying to run an espresso test that will ensure that the correct list item is showing the drawable for the status. I tried doing this:

```
 ViewInteraction imageView = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.client_state_image), withParent(withParent(withId(R.id.grid_view))), withDrawable(statusToCheck), isDisplayed()));
        imageView.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

With the withDrawable method drawn from [here](https://github.com/dbottillo/Blog/blob/espresso_match_imageview/app/src/androidTest/java/com/danielebottillo/blog/config/DrawableMatcher.java)

But I can't find a way to include the TextView in my assertion.

Is there a way to assert that a TextView and ImageView are displaying the correct information, together?